# Skip the first 5 elements "li" tag

Tags: loops, jsoup

I am working in a database, and I need to retrieve several information from the web. Reading the font code page with Jsoup, I want to skip te first 5 elements with "li" tag. I am trying this, but it is not working at all:

```
                    String letra=editText.getText().toString().toUpperCase();

                    String url="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_airports_by_ICAO_code:_"+letra;

                    try {
                        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
                        Elements liTags=doc.select("li");
                        int c=0;

                        for(org.jsoup.nodes.Element ligtag : liTags ){

                            if(c<5) {
                                frase =liTags.text()+" \r\n";
                                tv9.setText(" ");
                                c++;
                            }

                            else
                                frase =liTags.text()+" \r\n";
                                tv9.setText(frase);
                        }

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you look at your code in a debugger yet? I guess not, because there are several severe mistakes in it:

1. You cycle over `liTags` and `ligtag` contains the current element, yet you never use this element.
2. The `else block` is not surrounded by curly brackets, making only the first statement part of the `else`.
3. The `tv9.setText(frase);` line looks not good to me. I don't know what type tv9 is, but I guess that the setText method will not concatenate the new input to the already existing, but instead will replace the text value of the tv9 object. This is however only a guess.

Here is a working version that uses some CSS magic to get only the relevant li tags, instead of just leaving out the first 5 li elements:

```
String letra="F";
String url="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_airports_by_ICAO_code:_"+letra;
try {
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
    Elements liTags = doc.select("li:has(b:matches(^"+letra+"))");

    for(org.jsoup.nodes.Element liTag : liTags ){
        String frase = liTag.text()+" \r\n";
        System.out.print(frase);
    }

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The CSS selector selects all `li` tags that have a `b` tag inside which contains text starting with the letter you want.

**Addendum in response of comments**

For the letter "A" I get the following output:

```
AGAF (AFT) – Afutara Airport – Afutara 
AGAR (RNA) – Ulawa Airport – Arona, Ulawa Island 
AGAT (ATD) – Uru Harbour Airport – Atoifi, Malaita 
AGBA (VEV) – Barakoma Airport – Barakoma 
AGBT (BPF) – Batuna Airport – Batuna 
AGEV (GEF) – Geva Airport – Geva 
AGGA (AKS) – Auki Gwaunaru'u Airport – Auki 
AGGB (BNY) – Bellona/Anua Airport – Bellona/Anua 
AGGC (CHY) – Choiseul Bay Airport – Choiseul Bay, Taro Island 
AGGD (MBU) – Mbambanakira Airport – Mbambanakira 
AGGE (BAS) – Balalae Airport – Shortland Island 
AGGF (FRE) – Fera/Maringe Airport – Fera Island, Santa Isabel Island 
AGGG – Honiara FIR – Honiara, Guadalcanal 
AGGH (HIR) – Honiara International Airport (formerly Henderson Field) – Honiara, Guadalcanal 
AGGI – Babanakira Airport – Babanakira 
AGGJ (AVU) – Avu Avu Airport – Avu Avu 
AGGK (IRA) – Kirakira Airport – Kirakira 
AGGL (SCZ) – Santa Cruz/Graciosa Bay/Luova Airport – Santa Cruz/Graciosa Bay/Luova, Santa Cruz Island 
AGGM (MUA) – Munda Airport – Munda, New Georgia Island 
AGGN (GZO) – Nusatupe Airport – Gizo Island 
AGGO (MNY) – Mono Airport – Mono Island 
AGGP (PRS) – Marau Sound Airport – Marau Sound 
AGGQ (OTV) – Ontong Java Airport – Ontong Java 
AGGR (RNL) – Rennell/Tingoa Airport – Rennell/Tingoa, Rennell Island 
AGGS (EGM) – Seghe Airport – Seghe 
AGGT (NNB) – Santa Ana Airport – Santa Ana 
AGGU (RUS) – Marau Airport – Marau 
AGGV (VAO) – Suavanao Airport – Suavanao 
AGGY (XYA) – Yandina Airport – Yandina 
AGIN – Isuna Heliport – Isuna 
AGKG (KGE) – Kaghau Airport – Kaghau Island 
AGKU (KUE) – Kukudu Airport – Kukudu 
AGOK (GTA) – Gatokae Aerodrome – Gatokae 
AGRC (RIN) – Ringi Cove Airport – Ringi Cove 
AGRM (RBV) – Ramata Airport – Ramata Island 
ANAU – Nauru Flight Information Region 
ANYN (INU) – Nauru International Airport – Yaren 
AYAA (AMF) – Ama Airport – Ama 
AYBK (BUA) – Buka Airport – Buka 
AYCH (CMU) – Chimbu Airport – Kundiawa 
AYDU (DAU) – Daru Airport – Daru 
AYGA (GKA) – Goroka Airport – Goroka 
AYGN (GUR) – Gurney Airport – Alotau 
AYGR (PNP) – Girua Airport – Popondetta 
AYHK (HKN) – Hoskins Airport – Kimbe 
AYIQ (KIE) – Kieta Aropa Airport – Kieta 
AYKA (LSA) – Losuia Airport – Kiriwina 
AYKI (UNG) – Kiunga Airport – Kiunga 
AYKK (KRI) – Kikori Airport – Kikori 
AYKM (KMA) – Kerema Airport – Kerema 
AYKT (KZF) – Kaintiba Airport – Kaintiba 
AYKV (KVG) – Kavieng Airport – Kavieng 
AYKY – Kunaye Airport – Kunaye 
AYLA – Lae Airfield – Lae 
AYMD (MAG) – Madang Airport – Madang 
AYMH (HGU) – Mount Hagen Airport – Mount Hagen 
AYMN (MDU) – Mendi Airport – Mendi 
AYMO (MAS) – Momote Airport – Manus Island 
AYMR (MXH) – Moro Airport – Moro 
AYMS (MIS) – Misima Island Airport – Misima 
AYNZ (LAE) – Lae Nadzab Airport – Lae / Nadzab 
AYPY (POM) – Port Moresby/Jackson International Airport – Port Moresby 
AYRB – Rabaul Airport (old) (destroyed 1994) – Rabaul, New Britain 
AYTA (TIZ) – Tari Airport – Tari 
AYTB (TBG) – Tabubil Airport – Tabubil 
AYTK (RAB) – Rabaul Airport (Tokua Airport) – Rabaul / Tokua 
AYVN (VAI) – Vanimo Airport – Vanimo 
AYWD (WBM) – Wapenamanda Airport – Wapenamanda 
AYWK (WWK) – Wewak International Airport – Wewak
```

Both AYNZ and AYPY are part of the list.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply @luksch. By the way, it is just printing me the last element of all <li> tags, and I'd like to print them all. Any suggestion?

Comment: Did you copy/paste my suggestion? Note that I set `letra` to "F" as an example. I don't understand what you mean by "it is just printing me the last element of all <li> tags". Can you explain?

Comment: `Elements liTags = doc.select("li:has(b:matches(^"+letra+"))");` this should retrieve every <b> element with <li> tag, starting by "letra"? in case "letra" is A, there are almost 40 elements, but it is printing me just the last element of the supposed list...

Comment: Sorry, don't get it. The CSS selector seems to work for me. Maybe you should specify in your original question exactly what you want to get.

Comment: <li><b>AYNZ</b><li>,<li><b>AYPY</b><li>. Both AYNZ and AYPY are different airport. If I request `"li:has(b:matches(^A))"`, system should print both AYNZ and AYPY, but it just prints AYPY. Do you get it now?

Comment: I don't know. For me the program output is as expected. Both codes are part of the result list.

Comment: Also, look at the newly added point 3 in my answer. I guess that is your problem.

Comment: You were right, text view method was not ok... Thanks a lot mate!@luksch